# Inserting Date in mongoDb using mongoClient

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to insert a json data containing java.util.Date in MongoDB using mongoClient. While creating Document I am converting json to string  as below, due to which my insertOne api fails to insert data giving exception as 
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Mon' .

```
    public static void insert(MongoCollection collection, JSONObject 
         jsonObj) {

    Document dbObject = Document.parse(jsonObj.toString());                
    collection.insertOne(dbObject);
     }
```

How to create a Mongo Document from jsonObject without parsing it? should I iterate the json and go on appending to empty document? or is there any better way?

Comment: Do you have an option of massaging the `jsonObj`?